# How does Philosophy.SE deal with abusive users?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that there are a few users who seem to raise trouble. These are users whose only questions have received a number of downvotes. All of their questions are clearly (and knowingly) violating the community guidelines.

What do the moderators do to deal with such users? What should us (non-moderator) Philosophy.SE members do to deal with such users?

Answer (score 2):

Consistent trouble makers are dealt with as needed by moderators. We notice the patterns, in fact we have special tools which automatically alert us to these kinds of things. Users can help by flagging content appropriately, voting to close questions which are clearly violating guidelines, etc. If you have particular issue with a user, let us know and we'll do everything we can to help. :)

Comment: Converted this from a comment to get this question off my unanswered list... ;-)